# LoadError: cannot load such file -- .../advertisement_controller_spec.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

UPDATE: I've added the controller I'm testing and my gem file

I'm running tests on this controller and I'm getting this LoadError which I can't figure out where it's coming from. I've ran other tests in my app so I'm pretty sure rspec is running correctly.

Some other issues that may be related: When I first started my rails server the terminal returned

> Could not find proper version of railties (4.2.5) in any of the sources Run bundle install' to install missing gems.

I ran bundle install and the terminal returned

> An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that gem install pg -v '0.18.4' succeeds before bundling.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

controller spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'
include RandomData

RSpec.describe AdvertisementsController, type: :controller do

  let (:my_ad) do
    Advertisement.create(
    id: 1,
    title: RandomData.random_sentence,
    copy: RandomData.random_paragraph,
    price: 99
    )
  end

  describe "GET #index" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end

    it "assigns [my_ad] to @advertisements" do
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:advertisements)).to eq([my_ad])
    end
  end

end
```

Stack trace:

```
4DV3R54RYs-MBP:Development D35TR0Y3R$ rspec spec/controllers/advertisement_controller_spec.rb
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rspec-core-3.5.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in load: cannot load such file -- /Users/a666/Development/spec/controllers/advertisement_controller_spec.rb (LoadError)
    from /Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rspec-core-3.5.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in block in load_spec_files
    from /Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rspec-core-3.5.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1433:in each
    from /Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rspec-core-3.5.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1433:in load_spec_files
    from /Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rspec-core-3.5.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:100:in setup
    from /Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rspec-core-3.5.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in run
    from /Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rspec-core-3.5.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in run
    from /Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rspec-core-3.5.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in invoke
    from /Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rspec-core-3.5.3/exe/rspec:4:in <top (required)>
    from /Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/rspec:22:in load
    from /Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/rspec:22:in <main>
    from /Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in eval
    from /Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in <main>
```

Controller:

```
class AdvertisementsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
  end
end
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

 # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
 gem 'rails', '4.2.5'

 # #1
 group :production do
   gem 'pg'
   gem 'rails_12factor'
 end

 # #2
 group :development do
   gem 'sqlite3'
 end

 group :development, :test do
   gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
 end

 # Use SCSS for stylesheets
 gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
 # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
 # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
 gem 'jquery-rails'
 gem 'turbolinks'
 gem 'bootstrap-sass'
 gem 'pry-rails'
```

Comment: do you have Postgres installed on your system

Comment: It'll help if you could include both the gemfile and the controller

Comment: I don't know if I have postgres but one of the last packages I installed was postgresql. I'll update w/ gem file & controller.

Answer (score 0):

The file name seems singular `advertisement_controller_spec.rb` while the spec class name `AdvertisementsController` seems plural. Check if you are referring the right file name.